# To find maxima for Gaussian mixture model

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, mixture-distribution

I have a Gaussian mixture model with some parameters

mean=(506.8644,672.8448,829.902)

sigma=(61.02859,9.149168,74.84682)

c=(0.1241933, 0.6329082, 0.2428986)

And the plot look something like below. 
[image]

Also, if I change my parameters to

mean=(2.15,2.0,2.9)

sigma=(0.1,0.1,0.1)

c=(1/3,1/3,1/3)

Then plot would change to 
[image]

Is there any way to find the maxima. I have tried Newton's method but it gave me the wrong output.

Like in general some common solution, which would work on all the cases, is needed.Can someone suggest me how can I achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are going to have to edit your question with more detail to get any help with this. What stages did you go through to get to this point?

Answer (score 4):

As whuber mentioned below, the mode of the mixture may not be a mode of any component.

[This](https://www.utu.fi/en/units/sci/units/math/Research/optimization/Documents/sovmat13012012.pdf) seems to be a fairly comprehensive overview of mode-seeking algorithms for GMMs.

One technique is to run a local optimization algorithm centered on each mixture component.

According to the document, when all the components have equal variance, which is not the case here, this algorithm will almost always succeed, barring pathological cases. When the components do not have equal variance, there are no such guarantees.

Another method is to set the gradient of the likelihood to 0 and use the mean-shift algorithm for mode seeking:

$$
x \leftarrow \frac{\sum_i f_i(x)\mu_i}{\sum_i f_i(x)}
$$

where $x$ can be initialized to any reasonable value (or perhaps even multiple) and $f_i$ is the density of the $i$th component at $x$, accounting for the mixture weights.

This algorithm performs decently, but also seems to have no global convergence guarantees.

Finally, the method proposed in the document suggests finding the mode of the gaussian distribution by relaxing the original density into a very smooth mixture which only has one maximum, and iteratively tightening the mixture until it returns to the original mixture.

More concretely, the convolution of a gaussian with another gaussian results in a gaussian. Therefore, we can analytically convolve a smoothing gaussian with an GMM, giving us another GMM. If we make the variance of the smoothing gaussian sufficiently large, we will end up with a unimodal density.

At this point, we should maximize the likelihood, reduce the variance of the smoothing gaussian, and repeat. Do this until the variance reduces to 0, at which point we have found some mode of the original mixture.

The document claims that this algorithm will find either the global maximum or a mode which is close to the global maximum, but doesn't provide any guarantees.

Comment: +1 I suspect, but haven't proven, that starting a search at each mode of the components of a *Gaussian* mixture will always succeed at finding the mode of the mixture. One might need some assumptions about the minimum variance of the components. The relaxation method you mention at the end has long been used for analyzing geological logs: it works nicely because everything in sight is infinitely differentiable, making it possible to track maxima, minima, inflection points, etc. as well.

Comment: I also agree that starting at the modes for a 1D gaussian mixture sounds like it should work. Curiously, this seems not to work for 2D or higher. See the left half of this image: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~miguel/research/GMmodes/2Dnonisot.png

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that: higher dimensions are entirely different.

Comment: The document link doesn't work anymore.